# Is there Wordpress compatible extension that matches addresses with federal and state legislative districts?

Tags: wordpress

My organization is considering CiviCRM, but identifying both federal and state legislative districts for all supporters is a must have for us. We do a lot of state level work, so the state districts are just as important as federal. I see there is an option for Drupal, but we are Wordpress users. An older thread on this topic was inconclusive so I wanted to see if there were any new developments. Thanks!

Comment: [Joseph Lacey](https://github.com/josephlacey/) is working with [Lemniscus](https://lemnisc.us) to develop a new and improved CiviCRM-native extension that will look up electoral districts at the national and state/provincial levels. We'll post this as an answer once the work is complete. @joseph-lacey

Comment: There's an extension which does this for the United Kingdom which may prove useful. https://github.com/bhahumanists/bha.politicaldata - It would need reworking to work for the US.